# Link all LXC node APT caches to the host machine's APT cache

Tags: ubuntu, apt, chroot, lxc

I have a number of LXC containers (ubuntu template) which all have their own separate APT caches.

```
/var/lib/lxc/*/rootfs/var/cache/apt/archives/
```

I would like to have these linked to the host machines APT cache at:

```
/var/cache/apt/archives
```

From what I remember, symlinking out of a chroot jail is a massive no-no, so I was wondering what some other clean alternatives would be. One solution I thought of what just making a cron job on the host machine to sync with the guest containers, but I was wondering if there was any way I could handle this without having to schedule synchronizations? A symlink would just be so convenient, but it'd be a massive security hole, right?

Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `bind` mounts to make these all point to the same place.  For example:

```
mount --bind /var/cache/apt/archives /var/lib/lxc/foo/rootfs/var/cache/apt/archives
```

[This blog post](http://s3hh.wordpress.com/2011/09/22/sharing-mounts-with-a-container/) and [this forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1476832) talks about this solution in more detail.

A symlink wouldn't be a security hole, it simply wouldn't work, because from within the container a symlink to `/var/cache/apt/archives` would point at a location *inside* the container filesystem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I eventually realized that the various nodes could  possibly interfere with each other during simultaneous apt-get operations, so I went off searching again. I ended up coming across `apt-cacher-ng` which I'm going to give a test run. Your solution is working though in the short term as I only perform apt operations on the nodes manually at present. Cheers :)